# AWS API Gateway Override for this method

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

When an API is deployed to a stage in AWS API Gateway, it shows the following two options for each method :-
1. Inherit from Stage
2. Override for this method

These settings are quite easy to change from the AWS console.

How can this be done using the aws cli or programmatically using the boto3 SDK ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two options are differentiated by a wildcard in the resource-path and method:

```
aws apigateway update-stage --rest-api-id 1234123412 --stage-name 'dev' --patch-operations op=replace,path=/*/*/logging/dataTrace,value=true

aws apigateway update-stage --rest-api-id 1234123412 --stage-name 'dev' --patch-operations op=replace,path=/~1resource~1path/GET/logging/dataTrace,value=false
```

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/apigateway/update-stage.html

Comment: The above commands allow me to switch from Inherit from Stage to Override for this method. If required, How can I switch it back to Inherit from Stage ?  I tried setting the value to false, but that doesn't change it back to Inherit from Stage.

Comment: I checked again & value = false disables the feature, e.g. logging. So that works. Any options for reverting it back to Inherit from Stage ?