# How to enable method level trace in AWS API gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I want to enable API full trace on AWS API gateway method using CLI.

Method : POST

Method Path : /RetrieveAggregate/{cust_id}

payload.json file has the following

```
"patchOperations": [
        {
            "op": "replace",
            "path": "/~1RetrieveAggregate~1{cust_id}/POST/logging/loglevel",
            "value": "INFO"
        },
        {
            "op": "replace",
            "path": "/~1RetrieveAggregate~1{cust_id}/POST/logging/dataTrace",
            "value": "true"
        }
    ]
```

I am running following CLI command

```
aws apigateway update-method --rest-api-id tu******* --resource-id 7**** --http-method POST \
 --cli-input-json file://payload.json
```

The CLI errors with following message

```
An error occurred (BadRequestException) when calling the UpdateMethod operation: 
Invalid patch path /~1RetrieveAggregate~1{cust_id}/POST/logging/loglevel
```

When directly specifying the patch operation in the CLI command instead of JSON file.

```
aws apigateway update-method --rest-api-id tu******** --resource-id 7**** --http-method POST \
--patch-operations 'op=replace,path=/~1RetrieveAggregate~1{cust_id}/POST/logging/loglevel,value=INFO' \
--region "us-east-1"
```

I am getting following error.

```
Error parsing parameter '--patch-operations': Expected: ',', received: '}' for input:
op=replace,path=/~1RetrieveAggregate~1{cust_id}/POST/logging/loglevel,value=INFO
```

It seems that the path parameter doesn't allow "}". Does anyone know which character should be used to replace "}".
AWS API document only says that "/" should be replaced by "~1" but it doesn't say anything about "}".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have raised this with AWS support and got a response from them which says that I can update the method level with update-stage command.

```
aws apigateway update-stage --rest-api-id tu******** --stage-name 'live' --patch-operations \
'op=replace,path=/~1RetrieveAggregate~1*/POST/logging/loglevel,value=INFO' --region "us-east-1"
```

Note that curly brackets have been changed to wildcard (*).

Similar answer provided on the following link to set the method level trace using the update-stage option
[AWS API Gateway Override for this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47393366/aws-api-gateway-override-for-this-method)